# Show list of image by listview in QML

Tags: qt, listview, scroll, qml

I'm trying to make a listview image in bottom of a windows size 1920x1080. But I don't know how to use listview in QML to show image. Uhis is design

[image]

**Update:**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog   // call dialog
        visible: true
        title: "Choose a file"
        property url defaultz: "E:\IMG"
        folder: defaultz
        selectMultiple: true
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png *.bmp)", "All files (*)" ]
        onAccepted: {
            console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrls)
            console.log(fileDialog.fileUrls.length)
        }

        onRejected: {
            console.log("Canceled")
            fileDialog.visible = false
        }
    }
    ListView {   // call listview
        id: listview
        height: 100
        anchors{
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        delegate:
            Image {
            width: 160
            height: 90
            source: modelData
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        listview.model = fileDialog.fileUrls // here is caller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `ListView` and set the appropriate anchors:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: listview
        height: 100
        anchors{
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        delegate:
            Image {
            source: modelData
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var images = [
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                    "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png"
                ]
        listview.model = images
    }
}
```

[image]

or use a `Repeater`:

```
Row{
    anchors{
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        delegate:
            Image {
            source: modelData
        }
    }
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    var images = [
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png",
                "http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/declarative-qtlogo.png"
            ]
    repeater.model = images
}
```

**Update:**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        visible: true
        title: "Choose a file"
        property url defaultz: "E:\IMG"
        folder: defaultz
        selectMultiple: true
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png *.bmp)", "All files (*)" ]
        onAccepted: {
            var images = [];
            for(var i in fileDialog.fileUrls){
                images[i] = fileDialog.fileUrls[i]
            }
            listview.model = images
        }
        onRejected: fileDialog.visible = false
    }
    ListView {
        id: listview
        height: 100
        anchors{
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        delegate:
            Image {
            width: 160
            height: 90
            source: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to show different img in my show. Can I do it with row ?

Comment: I have a list of url from filedialog.

Comment: @TrungPC 
If you show me how you get the urls I could indicate how to do it.

Comment: I have url from FileDialog. It return a array urls. I can call it:  file.fileUrls[i]  - file: id of FileDialog

Comment: It did not work. file.fileUrls is a array. How can I call it ?

Comment: @TrungPC 
Sorry, it was my mistake, use `listview.model = file.fileUrls`

Comment: Can you help me fix it with teamview ?

Comment: @TrungPC no, if you want help, edit your question and show your code there.

Comment: @TrungPC I have already updated my answer, try it, on the other hand SO has predefined structured where there is a question and many answers, in your case if you want to add information you must edit your question, not create an answer, please read [ask] and [answer] so that in future occasions we can help you. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct.